# Raising a wheel onto a curb at an angle

Tags: torque

I am trying to find if there is a model to help explain the forces acting on a bicycle wheel when driving over a curb at an angle. Most of what I have found so far assumes the wheel hits the curb at a 90-degree angle, so you're primarily concerned with wheel radius and curb height.

I'm trying to find how one might calculate the point at which the angle would cause the wheel to be pushed away (causing a fall) before it could successfully mount the curb. Most of what I have been able to find assumes a car, turning on a flat surface, with no curb height. I am not a physicist, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The angle would be very dependent on friction, which would depend on the tire tread, curb surface, speed, tire pressure, weight of the rider, how much rider weight is on the front wheel, how much the rider resists the tendency for the handle bars to turn, etc. etc.  There are so many variables that I believe empirical testing to determine an approximate rule-of-thumb may be the best approach. Creating an analytical software model would not involve difficult physics, but it would certainly be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

There are neat examples of the relationship of wheel diameter, mass, and curb height you can watch on Youtube.  The equation for calculating the force is: F=(Mg√(2Rh-h^2 ))/(2R-h)  Hitting the curb at an angle draws in so many other variables as Will Mac points out. Inflation pressure would be very important. I think you would have to have a lab and reverse engineer an equation that might fit careful measurements.